# Caixa de pesquisa do próprio blog não funciona!

Tags: html, algoritmo-de-busca, blogger

A Caixa de pesquisa não funciona, eu digito o titulo do texto, as palavras chaves, e todas as palavras usadas no texto, e simplesmente aparece que não tem nenhum resultado...

Eu testei várias outras caixas de pesquisas e nem aparece nada... é algum problema no blog,no templete que estou usando, ou outro problema? 
Blog: http://test25897463.blogspot.com.br/

Eu realmente não sei forma melhor de fazer esta pergunta... Tudo que falei é o o que sei... Eu não posso editar esta caixa de pesquisa porque ela do próprio blogger... O máximo que posso fazer é mudar a aparência... só que tentei colocar todas as search box que eu encontrei e pior do que esta, é que não aparecem nada...

> Antes de me dar -1 poderia pelo menos me dizer como posso melhorar
>   para que eu possa ajudar voces a me ajudarem?

Comment: ela está sem função amigo, sem form

Comment: Mas  esta é a caixa de pesquisa do blog, tem alguma forma deu concertar isso? @VictorGomes

Comment: Eu realmente não sei forma melhor de fazer esta pergunta... Tudo que falei é o o que sei... Eu não posso editar esta caixa de pesquisa porque ela do próprio blogger... O máximo que posso fazer é mudar a aparência... só que tentei colocar todas as search box que eu encontrei e pior do que esta, é que não aparecem nada...

Comment: Visite a área [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do Stack e veja algumas formas de fazer perguntas corretamente. Enquanto ao seu problema, você já tentou deletar o widget e colocar de novo?

Comment: sim várias vezes... O problema é no blogger... Descobrir hoje no fórum do Google. Eu já li 'como fazer perguntas', mas eu acho que não exista forma melhor de fazer esta pergunta... É difícil fazer uma pergunta quando não se sabe qual é o problema... Eu havia tentando de tudo antes de vir até aqui, e perguntando em vários forums, só vim te a resposta hoje em um deles... @VictorGomes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, apos tentar de tudo, e perguntar em todo lugar, acabei recendo respostas no próprio fórum do Google, no fórum americano, um especialista me contou que o problema era porque o meu blog era de testes, e não tinha muito trafego, postagens e coisas do tipo... Por isso não aparecia nenhum resultado. De acordo com ele, na medida que eu fosse usando-o, ele funcionaria.

E no fórum do Google brasileiro, eu descobrir que isso está acontecendo com muitas pessoas, é um problema do blogger e eles estão tentando concertar a muito tempo. E pelo visto, não é um problema fácil. 
 Então, a solução seria utilizar outros tipos de caixas de pesquisas, que apesar de não serem iguais ao do blogger, pelo menos funcionam...

Aqui está uma que estou usando no meu blog (já que nem todas funcionam).

```
<style type="text/css">
#pesquisafsm-caixa {
background: #eee; padding:10px; border:0 none; width:170px;
}
#pesquisafsm-botao {
border: 1px solid #222;
color: #eee; 
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/cz4sguf.png) no-repeat left #4591fa;
margin-left: -3px;
color:#fff;
font: 'trebuchet ms', trebuchet;
padding:10px 10px 10px 22px;
border:0 none;
font-weight:bold;
border-top-right-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
#pesquisafsm-botao:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background:  url(http://i.imgur.com/cz4sguf.png) no-repeat left #2375E6;
}
</style>
<form action="/search" id="searchthis" method="get" style="display: inline;">
<input id="pesquisafsm-caixa" name="q" placeholder="O que está procurando?" size="40" type="text" /> 
<input id="pesquisafsm-botao" type="submit" value="Pesquisar" /> </form>
```

Tutorial da caixa de pesquisa: http://henriquezenny.blogspot.com.br/2013/10/caixa-de-pesquisa-em-css-para-blogger.html